# Unable to pass props using @Input() in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm working with very basic angular project. I want to pass props between two angular components. The properties of a component are working fine when directly rendering them in the relevant HTML file. When passing it to another component it shows error.

HTML file of the parent component

```
<app-todo-item *ngFor="let todo of todos" [todo]="todo">
</app-todo-item>
```

The child component:

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from 'src/app/models/Todo';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo-item',
  templateUrl: './todo-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo-item.component.css']
})
export class TodoItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() todo:Todo;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

The error I got:

```
Error: src/app/components/todo-item/todo-item.component.ts:11:12 - error TS2564: Property 'todo' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

Comment: You should not use deep imports like `import { Todo } from 'src/app/models/Todo';` use like `import { Todo } from './models/Todo';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That comes from the new Ts compiler. Can fix with:

```
@Input() todo?: Todo;
```

What tells compiler this property is optional. Or:

```
@Input() todo!: Todo;
```

What tells compiler this property will not be unassigned

Comment: It's better to use `todo?` instead of `todo!` as this is input it can be unassigned as well.